# Using lambda expressions for method call

Tags: c#, lambda

See I have this sample code

```
_service.GetCustomers((customers, error) =>
          {
             if (error != null)
             {                     
                MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
                return;
             }

             Customers = new ObservableCollection<CustomerViewModel>(customers);
             IsBusy = false;
          });
```

If I were to make a similar function call to another function which accepts more parameters how would that be. The function definition is like this

```
GetCustomers(DateTime sTime, int ID,  Action<IEnumerable<CustomerViewModel>, Exception> callback)
```

So how would the above function be invoked using the lambda expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambda expression is shorthand for an anonymous delegate which was introduced in C# 2.0 Action<T> and its siblings are generic delegates. Whenever you see an parameter of type Action<T> you can replace it with a lambda taking equivalent parameters. In this case it would be

```
service.GetCustomers(sometime, someId, (viewmodels, exception)=>{/*handle callback here*/});
```

Comment: What other generic delegates exist? beside Func<>

Comment: Action is the generic delegate with 0 to 5 parameters returning void. Func is the generic delegate with 0 to 5 parameters returning an object. Then there is EventHandler<T> which is the generic eventhandler delegate (allowing you to avoid a cast to a specific eventargs type). There are a few others but it's too late for me to think of them right now.

Answer (score 2):

```
_service.GetCustomers(datetime, id, (customers, error) => .....
... same as before
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply pass your anonymous delegate as before along with other parameters.

```
_service.GetCustomers(datetime, id, (customers, error) => {

                    if (error != null)
                    {                     
                        MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
                        return;
                    }

                    Customers = new ObservableCollection<CustomerViewModel>(customers);
                    IsBusy = false;

               });
```